# LabelEncoder TypeError?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, label, encoder

I'm trying to encode some text values with LabelEncoder. For this I'm writing:

```
onehot = pd.DataFrame()
encoders = []
for column in df_resolved.loc[:, ((df_resolved.dtypes != np.int64)&(df_resolved.dtypes != np.int32))]:
    enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    encoders.append(enc)
    onehot[column] = enc.fit_transform(df_resolved[column])
```

I need the encoding to be reproducible with new data, do I need to store the encoders, that's why I'm doing it this way. However, I get an error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

I don't understand why this is happening. The encoder should be able to encode strings according to the documentation. What am I missing?

Full stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-330-f9a564c7c9ab> in <module>()
      8     enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
      9     encoders.append(enc)
---> 10     onehot[column] = enc.fit_transform(df_resolved[column])

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    129         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    130         _check_numpy_unicode_bug(y)
--> 131         self.classes_, y = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
    132         return y
    133 

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    209 
    210     if optional_indices:
--> 211         perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort' if return_index else 'quicksort')
    212         aux = ar[perm]
    213     else:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

UPDATE:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1436 entries, 0 to 1706
Data columns (total 26 columns):
u_category                       1436 non-null object
caller_id.country                1436 non-null object
number                           1436 non-null object
priority                         1436 non-null object
urgency                          1436 non-null object
incident_state                   1436 non-null object
u_subcategory                    1436 non-null object
assigned_to                      1436 non-null object
short_description                1436 non-null object
sys_created_on                   1436 non-null datetime64[ns]
business_duration                1436 non-null int64
u_resolved_time                  1436 non-null datetime64[ns]
u_reopen_count                   1436 non-null int64
sys_created_by                   1436 non-null int64
caller_id.u_display_name         1436 non-null object
u_on_behalf_of.u_display_name    1436 non-null object
u_on_behalf_of.email             1436 non-null object
u_actual_time_to_resolve         1436 non-null int64
comments                         1436 non-null object
u_comments_and_work_notes        1436 non-null object
description                      1436 non-null object
impact                           1436 non-null object
u_problem_classification         1436 non-null object
resolution_time                  1436 non-null float64
rawtext                          1436 non-null object
cluster                          1436 non-null int32
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(1), int32(1), int64(4), object(18)
memory usage: 337.3+ KB
```

This is the df info. My SKLearn is version 0.18.1.

Comment: Could you also share smaller made up dataframe that reproduces the same error with us? Or at least add df_resolved.info()! Also, be aware that label encoder would not do the onehot encoding.

Comment: Also, you are appending the instance of LabelEncoder in the encoders list. You need to fit the instance first and then append it to your list.

Comment: Final comment: what is the version of your sklearn? I created the following dataframe and it worked fine for me without any errors. I am using version '0.17.1'. 
`df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','b','c','d'], 'B': [1,2,3,4], 'C': ['a','t',4,None]})`

my code was:

`onehot = pd.DataFrame(); encoders = []; 
for column in df.loc[:, ((df.dtypes != np.int64)&(df.dtypes != np.int32))]: enc = LabelEncoder(); encoders.append(enc.fit(df[column])); onehot[column] = enc.transform(df[column]);
`

Comment: @MhFarahani Thank you, I'll check your code! I've updated the question with the information you asked for. :)

Comment: Hm, I actually get the same error for your code, too... Weird because it did work before, then I tried some other things, wanted to use the encoder again in a different scenario and now it's not working...